# Exception java.lang.SecurityException: reading ..MediaDocumentsProvider ... requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()

Tags: android, android-manifest, file-permissions, android-permissions, document-provider

I found this issue only in some devices when trying to pick the picture for the profile image. While checking in the emulator these issue are not seen but on live version of the app this issues are facing by this users. **Screenshot captured from the firebase crash report.** Please help me to figure out the issue.

**AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
...
```

**SomeActivity.java**

```
private void pickProfilePictureTask() {

    Intent intent = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {

        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    } else {

        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    }

    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICKER_REQUEST);


}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


        if (data != null) {
            /**Getting bitmap
             *
             * InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
             * Bitmap userPicBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
             */
            File file = new File(getFileNameFromURI(data.getData()));
            String imageName = file.getPath();
            uploadProfilePicture.setText(imageName);
            userProfilePicUri = data.getData() + "";

        }


    }
}

private String getFileNameFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

**ERROR in Android 5.1.1** *Exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider* uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A6617 from pid=19207, uid=10260 *requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()*

[image]

**ERROR in Android 8.0.0** Exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{5c1039e 5061:com.mobotechnology.cvmaker/u0a219} (pid=5061, uid=10219) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing the code that is triggering these crashes. My guess is that you are trying to persist a `Uri` and use it later, and that only works if you use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, etc.) and take persistable `Uri` permissions.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating the answer? @CommonsWare

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to persist the Uri and use that Uri later. But I didn't get your answer. So, do you mind elaborating it? @CommonsWare

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I am trying to persist the Uri and use that Uri later

That will work for a `Uri` with a `file` scheme. It will not work for most `Uri` values with a `content` scheme. Those are more akin to an HTTP URL to an authenticated Web site — the URL is good while your session is alive but is useless afterwards.

*If* you obtain the `Uri` via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, *and* you call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on `ContentResolver` supplying the `Uri`, *then* you can safely persist that `Uri`. You will have access to the content indefinitely, until the user revokes access or the content significantly changes (e.g., is deleted) such that its `Uri` is no longer valid.

Any other `content` `Uri` (e.g., `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`) is only good [for a very short time](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html). Your only option here is to copy the content to some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`) and save the path to that file.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understand this permission model. Getting "No persistable permission grants found for UID".  when calling takePersistableUriPermission()

Comment: @frankelot: Are you using the `Uri` delivered to you by `onActivityResult()` or the contract? If you are, then presumably the documents provider is not offering persistable permission grants -- that's not a requirement. Where are you getting the document from?

Comment: Thanks for the reply CommonsWare. Totally my bad, I was using ACTION_GET_CONTENT, switching to ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public static final int KITKAT_VALUE = 1002;

Intent intent;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
    intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);
} else {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == KITKAT_VALUE ) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // do something here
        }
    }
}
```